# iOS shortening a firebase dynamic link returning an error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an iOS app that creates a firebase dynamic link based on a url passed to it. Creating the link works fine but when I try to shorten it, the completion handler return the error:

Error Domain=com.firebase.durabledeeplink Code=0 "API key is missing." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=API key is missing.}

Even though the error says that the API key is missing. I checked the google services plist and the API key is there.

My Code

```
            if let downloadUrl = downloadUrl {
                let dynamicLinksDomain = self.domainLink
                let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: downloadUrl, domain: dynamicLinksDomain)
                if let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder.url {
                    print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")
                }
                linkBuilder.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
                    if let url = url {
                        print("The short URL is: \(url)")
                        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
                        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Error shortening the url: \(String(describing: error))")       
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have been trying to work this out for the past day and am getting nowhere. Can someone help with this thanks.

Comment: Are you using latest version of `FirebaseDynamicLinks.framework`? If you use cocoapods for integration - you have a very outdated version. Try downloading newest version from here: https://firebase.google.com/download/ios

Comment: Did you remember to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` ?

Comment: Also, I would not recommend downloading the library manually if you're already using cocoapods -- as long as you've run a pod update recently, you should have a reasonably up-to-date version.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?